# Error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string " showing for one range and not for another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my monthly report generation, whenever I update data for some range it gets successfully generated,whereas not for others.

Code 1 (it works):

```
update warehouse_ticket_header 
set resolution_time = CONVERT(varchar(17), resolution_time_duplicate, 120) 
where 
    open_date_time between '03/01/2015' and '05/01/2015' 
    and config_item like '%Merlin%' 
    and resolution_time_duplicate is not null 
    and resolution_time is null
```

But when I query for June (month number 6), it shows error

Code 2 (Doesn't work)

```
update warehouse_ticket_header 
set resolution_time = CONVERT(varchar(17), resolution_time_duplicate, 120) 
where 
    open_date_time between '03/01/2015' and '06/01/2015' 
    and config_item like '%Merlin%' 
    and resolution_time_duplicate is not null 
    and resolution_time is null
```

Comment: Then why is this error not observed in the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use DATETIME datatype and unambiguous datetime format YYYYMMDD format

```
update warehouse_ticket_header 
set resolution_time = resolution_time_duplicate
where open_date_time >= '20150301' and open_date_time <='20150601' 
and config_item like '%Merlin%' 
and resolution_time_duplicate is not null and  resolution_time is  null
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your first query works fine i cant complain the statement rather it should be the data which is causing trouble. I suggest declaring parameters like @startdate and @enddate with data type DATE and assign to the query. This way we are making sure the system uses the strings being provided as date.

Hope this helps!